# Fill a List<string> inside a known object with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am quite new to Linq but just wanted to ask how to fill a `List<String>` of an object using LINQ?

What im trying to do is to bring all the URLs from a specific user. This data is stored in an Azure Table

My code is :

```
public IEnumerable<UserTable> getUserImages(UserTable pUser) {
    var results = from u in this.context.usersTableQuery
                  where u.UserName == pUser.UserName
                  select u.PhotosUrl //PHOTOS URL IS A LIST of strings and I know im missing something here
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to save the list on the passed in `pUser` or just return a list of strings for that one user?

Comment: I am trying to save the passed list into pUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your query always returns one user, and you want his `PhotosUrl` list. When that's true you should use that:

```
var user = this.context.usersTableQuery.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == pUser.UserName);

List<string> results;
if(user == null)
    results = new List<string>();
else
    results = user.PhotosUrl;
```

If there is any chance that query returns more than one user with given UserName, you have to use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548748.aspx) extension method:

```
List<string> results = this.context.usersTableQuery
                                   .Where(u => u.UserName == pUser.UserName)
                                   .SelectMany(u => u.PhotosUrl)
                                   .ToList();
```

`SelectMany` hasn't got an associated keyword in syntax based queries. It's gonna flatten your result from `List<List<string>>` into `List<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
   List<String>  results =( from u in this.context.usersTableQuery
                                  where u.UserName == pUser.UserName
                                  select u.PhotosUrl).ToList ()
```

Comment: The returned value of that query is different than List<string> expected, it is infact nested under System.Collections.Gneric.List<System.Collections.generic.List<string> .. I tried doing .ToList<string>() at the end but it wont work..

Comment: Its type is List<string> photosUrl;

Comment: .ToList() will create a list with the data and return it, I wanted to fill a List<String> property of the user object hehe